# Adding new instances to clusterer

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka

I'm currently using Weka's SimpleKMeans clusterer.
I would like to cluster new unseen instances into either a pre existing cluster or to a new cluster.

How can you cluster unseen instances into a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the question but if you are looking for methods that can capture more (or less) than a predetermined number of clusters, I would suggest you look into a non-parametric clustering algorithm such as Dirichlet Process Mixture.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I initialise my clusters using a dataset to generate k clusters. After this, I want to perform cosine similarity between each new document and each cluster. if the similarity is below a threshold then create a cluster else add to a pre existing cluster.

Comment: Yep, it sounds exactly like a non-parametric clustering problem. Look into Dirichlet process mixture, it should be the easiest one to follow.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to add new instances is to use the MacQueen k-means approach from the original "kmeans" publication.

I don't think Weka can do this out of the box, so you'll have to write the code yourself. But it is as easy as it can get!